# Is it necessary to unbind/off JQuery click event inside Knockout custom binding?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Given the scenario below is it necessary to unbind click event inside custom binding handler init using `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback`? Or does Knockout has it's own mechanism to automatically dispose/unbind event created inside custom binding handler?

Example :

```
<li>
   <a id='aTagId' data-bind='something'></a>
   <button data-bind: myCustomBinding:{}>       
</li>

ko.bindingHandlers.myCustomBinding=
{
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        $('#aTagId').on('click', function() { /*something in here*/ });

        // Is this code necessary?      
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function ()
        {
            $('#aTagId').off('click');
        });
    }
}
```

Note : Please don't ask me why I can't just put `myCustomBinding` in `<a>` tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it makes sense for event handlers attached to long-living objects(`window`, `document` etc):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var handler = function () {};

        $(window).on("resize", handler);

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(window).off("resize", handler);
        });
    })
};
```

See also - http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/10/knockout-cleaning-up.html

But in your scenario

**Firstly** your element is already removed when you're trying to call `off`:

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
   $('#aTagId').off('click'); //<== $('#aTagId').length is 0
});
```

You can rewrite it as follows:

```
var $aTag = $('#aTagId').on('click', function() {});

ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
 $aTag.off('click');
});
```

**But secondly** knockout has it's own mechanism to automatically dispose/unbind event. It's running `jQuery.cleanData`

```
// Perform cleanup needed by external libraries (currently only jQuery, but can be extended)
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal["cleanExternalData"](node);

...
"cleanExternalData" : function (node) {
   // Special support for jQuery here because it's so commonly used.
   // Many jQuery plugins (including jquery.tmpl) store data using jQuery's equivalent of domData
   // so notify it to tear down any resources associated with the node & descendants here.
   if (jQueryInstance && (typeof jQueryInstance['cleanData'] == "function"))
     jQueryInstance['cleanData']([node]);
}
```

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/241c26ca82e6e4b3eaee39e3dc0a92f85bc1df0c/src/utils.domNodeDisposal.js#L88-L94

This way your handler will be automatically disposed

[image]

Comment: This answer make sense to me. I tried to find the click event inside addDisposeCallback but can't find the event anymore even the `<a>` tag still exists. Thanks!

Comment: so is the code uncessary to call .off in when knockout.js does it anyway?